# dlib http server shows website as plain html with no javascript/css

Tags: javascript, c++, html, css, httpserver

I tried to implement a small http server in my c++ program to use a website as an interface using the dlib library (http://dlib.net/network.html#server_http). What this code should do is read an input html file on request and return it.

```
class web_server : public server_http
{
    const std::string on_request ( 
        const incoming_things& incoming,
        outgoing_things& outgoing
    )
    {
        ostringstream sout;
        sout<<get_file_contents("Seite.html");
        return sout.str();
    }

};
```

It does work but my browser shows just the plain html site without any javascript/css elements. These are integrated in the html file via:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scripte.js")>
   </script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
```

The html looks fine if I open it with the browser directly.
Thanks in advance

Edit: Thanks do  Davis King I got at least the javascript working, while the css still refuses to work. I managed to put in a generic response which now sends any requested file as string: body of on_request:

```
ostringstream sout;
sout<<get_file_contents("Seite.html");
cout << "request path: " << incoming.path << endl;
string filename=incoming.path.substr(1,incoming.path.length()); 
if (incoming.path.substr(0,1) == "/" && incoming.path.length()>1) return get_file_contents(filename.c_str());
return sout.str();
```

Edit again:
It works now. Chrome gave me hint, it said that the MIME type of the stylesheet file is text/html, but it's supposed to be text/css. I changed my response method accordingly and it works now:

```
if (incoming.path=="/Style.css") outgoing.headers["Content-Type"] == "text/css";
```

As a follow up question: Why do the css and js files trigger a request, and not the images I referenced in the html, which seem to work as far as I can tell with the messed layout?
But thanks a lot anyway, I'd upvote you but I sadly cannot...

Comment: What are the URLs for the images?  If they work the must be URLs for images on some other server.

Comment: Here is an example of a file that is stored locally:               <img src="../data/animation.gif"> </img> As it shows in the console a proper request is sent but I totally don't get how my generic response for plain text files works with a gif

Comment: Bytes are bytes, so if all you do is read the bytes from the disk and return them then it will work no matter what's in the file.  However, you might find that you need to set the Content-Type for some files so the browser will realize what to do with it, but by and large it should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is going to request the Style.css and scripte.js files from the web server, but the way you have written it, it will only ever respond with the Seite.html file.  So you have to add something like this to your on_request method:

```
cout << "request path: " << incoming.path << endl;
if (incoming.path == "/scripte.js")
    return get_file_contents("scripte.js");
else if (incoming.path == "/Style.css")
    return get_file_contents("Style.css");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but while your answer sounds reasonable, it does not work. The console shows the request path correctly, but the view does not change at all. The javascript and css files are in the same directory as the server executable and the html file though.

Comment: Whoa I just realised, the javascript part does indeed work now, I just didn't see it first because css does not work and I can't see a whole lot. Still no idea why css doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the browser has cached the previous response to Style.css?  Do you see it requesting the Style.css file?

Comment: How can I check this? I reloaded via F5 a hundred times and have also restarted severals times, so I don't think it's cached. It shows the proper request in the console. I have updated the code and a small follow up question, edited in my op if you could have a look!

Comment: Another thing: If I put my stylesheet in the header, it does work! ALso, if I use the chrome elements panel it shows the css file under ressources. But if I inspect the elements themselves, it sais under "matched css rules" user agent stylesheet.